# jetty 6.x on ubuntu jaunty 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-9.04, jetty, slicehost

I am a complete newbie - to sys admin. Actually, I don't know if I should ask this to developers or sys admins.

I am trying to configure a 256mb slice on slicehost - intending to install Jetty 6/7. I looked up the documentation and found everything related to Jetty 5.x.
The docs I see for Jetty 6 - going by manual installation - I am confused about the installation directory and I fear I will mess it up.

I did come across informative page on the jetty site at  http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debian+Packages , but when I tried installing, I got "couldn't find package". I browsed thru the 6.1.8 folders (http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/) and found no debian packages for Jetty.

1) Does anyone have any idea about installing Jetty 6.x or 7?

2) If not, is there a "safe" way to install a deb package[safe = ensuring that install is as if i did a `apt-get install`]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. jetty is currently just support by debian sid. Debian sid is the unstable branch, which will become the new stable on the next release. You could try to backport the package to your current system but this is not a trivial task.
2. You can use dpk -i pkgname to install a single debian package. Missing dependencies are not automatically installed, so this is not exactly what apt-get would do.

The easiest way to install jetty would be to download the binary package, extract it and start the included startscript. If you want it to be started on reboot you could write a init-script to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the binary package, you can use the script jetty.sh(under bin directory) as the init script. Copy it to /etc/init.d, then use update-rc.d command to install it. Also need two configuration files: /etc/default/jetty and /etc/jetty.conf, see comments in the jetty.sh for details.